# Querying postgres database with rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pg

I'm trying to search my database based on params from a search form. I had it working perfectly fine in SQLlite, but when I migrated to postgres, several things broke. in app/views/index.html.erb I defined a form:

```
<tr>
<%= form_tag(guidelines_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <td><%= label_tag(:invprogsearch, "Search by Investor and Program")%></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag :investor, nil, placeholder: "Enter investor" %></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag :program_code, nil, placeholder: "Enter program" %></td>
  <td><%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
```

and in my controller (app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb) I defined the index action as such

```
def index
    if params[:investor].present? && params[:program_code].present?
      @guidelines = Guideline.where(investor: params[:investor], program: params[:program_code])
    else
      @guidelines = Guideline.all
    end
end
```

Any idea why this wouldn't work? I'm out of ideas. Thanks!

app/models/guideline.rb:

```
class Guideline < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :guide_desc, presence: true

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Guideline'
  has_many   :children, class_name: 'Guideline', foreign_key: 'parent_id'

  scope :top_level, where(:parent_id => nil)

  def descendants
    self_and_descendants - [self]
  end

  def self_and_descendants
    self.class.tree_for(self)
  end

  def self.tree_for(instance)
    where("#{table_name}.id IN (#{tree_sql_for(instance)})").order("#{table_name}.id")
  end

  def self.tree_sql_for(instance)
    tree_sql =  <<-SQL
      WITH RECURSIVE search_tree(id, path) AS (
          SELECT id, ARRAY[id]
          FROM #{table_name}
          WHERE id = #{instance.id}
        UNION ALL
          SELECT #{table_name}.id, path || #{table_name}.id
          FROM search_tree
          JOIN #{table_name} ON #{table_name}.parent_id = search_tree.id
          WHERE NOT #{table_name}.id = ANY(path)
      )
      SELECT id FROM search_tree ORDER BY path
    SQL
  end
end
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "broke"? What does `Guideline` look like?

Comment: Specifically talking about different queries that need to be run. Added guideline to my question

Comment: But what broke in PostgreSQL that was working in SQLite? The query in your `index` controller? The recursive CTE? Any error messages?

Comment: No error messages. The query in my controller only searches on the first parameter, not on both like I would want

Comment: So `Guideline.where(investor: params[:investor], program: params[:program_code])` is ignoring the `:program`?

Comment: Yeah that's what's happening

Comment: What is in `params` when this happens? What is the SQL that gets sent to the database? Are you certain that it is your `index` controller that is being executed?